# Graph stored as adjacency list or as endpoints and intervals

Tags: java, performance, comparative-review, graph

I tried speeding up my Graph class, so I removed the Node class and Edge class, and decided to use arrays and `ArrayList`s. My 2 implementations seem very similar, but for some reason have a 10x performance speed difference that I cannot figure out.

For both of these, the constructor takes N = # nodes, M = # edges, and 2 arrays of length M that represent the endpoints of the edges.

Here is the first one that I found the pseudo-code for online, and implemented myself. Basically, it stores the edges with endpoints, all of them together in one array. Each node stores l and r, which represent the interval of its edges. I suspect this is for better cache performance, because everything is close together in memory.

```
class Graph1 {
    int[] edgeEndpoints;
    int[] l, r;
    
    public Graph1(int N, int M, int[] edgeArr1, int[] edgeArr2) {
        edgeEndpoints = new int[2*M];
        l = new int[N];
        r = new int[N];
        
        //calculate d
        int[] nodeDegrees = new int[N];
        for(int ele : edgeArr1)
        {
            nodeDegrees[ele]++;
        }
        for(int ele : edgeArr2)
        {
            nodeDegrees[ele]++;
        }
        
        //similar to N array lists. have a pointer cnt for each node. The interval of each node is already calculated
        int[] cnt = new int[N];
        l[0] = 0;
        r[0] = nodeDegrees[0]-1;
        for(int i=1; i<N; i++) {
            l[i] = r[i-1] + 1;
            r[i] = l[i] + nodeDegrees[i] - 1;
            cnt[i] = l[i];
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int a = edgeArr1[i];
            int b = edgeArr2[i];

            edgeEndpoints[cnt[a]] = b;
            edgeEndpoints[cnt[b]] = a;
            cnt[a]++;
            cnt[b]++;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this was needlessly complicated, so I tried making simple adjacency list implementation:

```
class Graph2 {
    ArrayList<Integer>[] edgeEndpoints; 
    
    public Graph2(int N, int M, int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        edgeEndpoints = new ArrayList[N];
        
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            edgeEndpoints[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
            int a = arr1[i];
            int b = arr2[i];
            edgeEndpoints[a].add(b);
            edgeEndpoints[b].add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

I then tested both of these with a randomly generated list of edges, with 1 million nodes and 4 million edges. The first version built in ~100ms, while the second one built in ~1500ms. What is causing this huge difference? I suspect it is due to memory access patterns, but even in the first example, some of it is still random.

Also, there might be some formatting errors; I just whipped these up in a few hours. I'm only worried about performance for now, and I will fix the formatting / clean up the code myself later, after I figure out why there is a performance difference.

Comment: It's not always clear to people how this site works.  "I'm only worried about performance for now, and I will fix the formatting / clean up the code myself later"  That's not it.  If you put it here for review, any and all aspects of the code are up for review.  We're not really a "call your shot" kind of site.  "Questions" here are simply the code that you want reviewed.  "Answers" are reviews.  Unlike other sites, you don't ask questions that you want answered, even though we use the same format.  Code Review is not really a Q&A site.

Comment: While formatting problems may not matter to you, they make the actual review more difficult because the code is less readable than it should be. So it comes out as a bit arrogant when you skip the work that you know that you should have done and thus make the volunteers work harder for you.